# Java - How can I insert user input position in existing array

Tags: java, arrays, oop, input

I am pretty new in Java. I am developing a Java console application which has a field and a frog jumping around in it, the user decides the size of the field through input in a 2d array, (kind of like a chess board but the difference is that the user decides how big the field should be). For instance the users enter height of field in feet and the width in feet. So far I have managed to do a bit of the class Field and class Position, which takes input from user and puts it on a array (int [][]fieldsize).

Class Controller:

```
package project;
public class Controller {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Field field = new Field();
        Position position = new Position();
        }
  }
```

Class Field:

```
package project;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Field{

    int y;
    int x;
    int[][] fieldsize;

    public Field() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out
                 .println("Enter the size of the field in feets(width
        and length separated by space, x y):");
        x = scan.nextInt();
        y = scan.nextInt();

        int[][] fieldsize = new int[y][x];

        this.fieldsize= fieldsize;

    }

    public int[][] getFieldSize() {
        return fieldsize;
    }
}
```

I have managed to "collect" the fields size from user input into int [][] fieldsize array.

Now I want to ask the user about the starting position for the frog and the heading direction, S(south), N(north), E(east), W(west) and then add the frog to the field. For instance the user types 3 4 E. This should put the frog to position [3] [4] East(Heading). How do I resolve this?

Class Position:

```
package project;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Position {

           public Position() {
              int x;
              int y;
              String heading;
              Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

                        System.out.println("Enter the starting position and heading for the frog, X Y and N, S, W or E position");
                        x = scan.nextInt();
                        y = scan.nextInt();
                        heading = scan.next(); 
                        //How do I put this inputs in the Field(fieldsize)?? So they get into this position in the field??


                        }

          }
```

It is a bit difficult to describe what I mean, but I hope you guys can help me!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

OK. First thing you should consider before starting to code - what is the design. And the question like this usually appears when the code comes before the design.

So the first question should be:
What classes do I need and what every class should do and how would they interact.

> An object is a self-contained component that contains properties and
>   methods needed to make a certain type of data useful. An object’s
>   properties are what it knows and its methods are what it can do.

For example - What can the object of the class `Field` do? How would it interact with the `Position`? And what can I do with the `Position`?

Then you start to design the classes. You sure don't want to read the user input in a constructor.  What if you want to get the input from the file tomorrow and get it from the cloud or by voice the next month? Or even worse - what if there is an input error? What would be the state of the object?

You usually need to provide all the data needed to create the object to the constructor. The constructor shouldn't care where you get it from. You can have a `public Field(int x, int y)` and call it in your main class after reading the user input (I'm not suggesting that you should have this exact constructor, just an example).

You may want to set the position as a method of the `Field` (field will contain the position)

```
field.setPosition(position);
```

or have a move method of the `Position`  (you can have as much positions as you like on the field)

```
position.setField(field);
position.moveTo(x,y);
```

Or you can even get to the conclusion you don't need a Position at all, and it would merely be the Field's property:

```
field.setCurrentX(x);
field.setCurrentY(y);
```

The design is really up to you here. Just have the design before you code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will look at the design.